# How to make Kubuntu display date and time in English?

Tags: kubuntu, language-support, time, locale, timezone

I am using Kubuntu 18.04 and it seems that despite having my whole system being setup in English, the date and time display (like days) is sometimes displayed in French, it seems related to the timezone but I am not sure.

How can I change that?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you relogin/reboot after having changed everything to en_US?

Comment: @Gunnar yes I did, still the same.